# How to calculate a location prior in CT's based on atlas segmentation?

Tags: cnn, autoencoder

I'm working myself through the paper "Anatomical Priors in Convolutional Networks for
Unsupervised Biomedical Segmentation" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03148)

I lack to understand how the atlas based prior is calculated in 4.3, any hints for me? I've spent some time on research about this, but unfortunately couldn't find a satisfying answer for myself..

> The decoder is a mirror of this design, but upsamples instead of
>   downsampling and ends with a sigmoid activation. In addition, we use a
>   final layer that implements a pixelwise spatially-varying voxel-wise
>   (location) prior ploc(s), which is multiplied with dec(z) (in
>   practice, we add the logarithms). As is common in the atlas-based
>   segmentation literature, the prior ploc(s) was computed as the
>   frequency of labels in the held out prior dataset, in
>   affine-normalized coordinate system. This layer discourages any
>   extreme decodings of z but does not capture shape properties, which is
>   encoded in dec(z).

Thanks!